# What is the resource impact of setting h.264 GOV length to maximum (or past spec'd max)

Tags: video, encoding, embedded-resource, h.264, mpeg-4

if I encode something using the baseline profile, but set key frame to maximum (or extended past the maximum and fix the player to support extended key frame intervals), what would the impact on encoder and decoder resources be (if everything else remained the same).

Does ram usage skyrocket?

Comment: You mean set the GOV length to 1? What do you mean by "setting a key frame to maximum"?

Comment: Yes, I meant the GOV. Basically given that in the situation I am going to be using h.264 (or a modified version) I know that rate of change for the scene is extremely low, and the pressure to reduce bitrate very high. So I was thinking that the distance between I frames could be stretched a lot further than in typical cases.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought that you want more key frames in your stream. Theoretically I can't think of the reason why you shouldn't set the GOV to be 100 (or more) at 10fps, you will have a key frame each 10 seconds. That will work. But I cant tell you for sure what will happen to ram. My guess is that it's usage will stay the same... Why don't you try it and see? :b

Comment: enter your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically I can't think of the reason why you shouldn't set the GOV to be 100 (or more) at 10fps, you will have a key frame each 10 seconds. That will work. But I cant tell you for sure what will happen to ram. My guess is that it's usage will stay the same... Why don't you try it and see? :b

Comment: It seems to me that it should increase RAM usage. What do you think will really happen?